# How do I display mails sent from a WP contact form?

Tags: wordpress

actually i am doing contact us form. in there i used one plug in. sending mails to admin...fine. but at the same i want to display at admin side. how to do? i am new to wordpress.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the messages on the Admin Dashboard?

Comment: I've fixed the heading of your quesion and the formatting. If it's inaccurate, please let me know/fix it.

Comment: yes. i have one doubt. please clarify. if there is no email sending option in contact form then i am inserting in database. then those details( username, email, message) how to fetch at admin side using the heading of contacted users. how to create left panel widget in admin side for that

Answer (score 0):

When you send emails to an admin, you can see those in the admins mailbox. They're not "messages" of any special kind. If you want those, you can use comments on posts.

Comment: thanks for changing the question. how to do. actually contactus page is plugin. how to comment?

Comment: i want to do send mail to admin, at the same contactus details will be display in admin side. i hope r u understood my problem.

thanks.

Comment: It's hard to give you a step by step solution. You do some reading and try out wordpress. If you hit a problem, we can try to rectify it. 

Try making a contact-us page without an email form but with just a plain vanilla stock comment form. Don't display submitted comments on the front end. The admin panel will have a list of comments submitted which you can look through.